# Spark mllib threshold for f1score

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to find the optimal threshold to have my logistic regression have the highest f1 score. However, when I wrote the following lines :

```
val f1Score = metrics.fMeasureByThreshold
f1Score.foreach { case (t, f) =>
println(s"Threshold: $t, F-score: $f, Beta = 1")
```

Some weird values appeared, for example :

```
Threshold: 2.0939996826644833, F-score: 0.285648784961027, Beta = 1
Threshold: 2.093727854652065, F-score: 0.28604171441668574, Beta = 1
Threshold: 2.0904571465313113, F-score: 0.2864344637946838, Beta = 1
Threshold: 2.0884466833553468, F-score: 0.28682703321878583, Beta = 1
Threshold: 2.0882666552407283, F-score: 0.2872194228126431, Beta = 1
Threshold: 2.0835997800203447, F-score: 0.2876116326997939, Beta = 1
Threshold: 2.077892816382506, F-score: 0.28800366300366304, Beta = 1
```

How is it possible to have a threshold greater than one ? The same goes for negative values which are displayed further in the console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a mistake earlier when converting my Dataframe to an RDD, instead of writing :

```
val  predictionAndLabels =predictions.select("probability", "labelIndex").rdd.map(x => (x(0).asInstanceOf[DenseVector](1), x(1).asInstanceOf[Double]))
```

I wrote :

```
val  predictionAndLabels =predictions.select("rawPredictions", "labelIndex").rdd.map(x => (x(0).asInstanceOf[DenseVector](1), x(1).asInstanceOf[Double]))
```

So the thresholds were about the rawPredictions and not the probabilities, everything makes sense now